# Elegant way to get all objects of a specific type in an Objective-C array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, reflection

I know I can do

```
for (id obj in array)
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[Elephant class]])
        [elephants addObject:obj];
}
```

but I feel there must be a more elegant way of doing this. I've looked at filtering arrays but can't come up with a good predicate. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The predicate would be something like

```
Class ec = [Elephant class];
NSPredicate *elePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class==%@", ec];
NSArray *elephants = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:elePred];
```

or

```
NSPredicate *elePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", ec];
```

I have found predicates to be quite, er.. shall we say "Heavy". I would probably prefer your code to this.

If you are just looking to spice up your life a little you could use blocks to add a little concurrency…

```
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[Elephant class]])
            [results addObject:obj];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create category to `NSMutableArray` and add next method:

```
- (void)addObject:(id)anObject ifItIsKindOfClass:(Class) classObj {
    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:classObj]) {
        [self addObject:anObject];
    }
}
```

And simple write:

```
for (id obj in array)
{
        [elephants addObject:obj ifItIsKindOfClass:[Elephant class]];
}
```

There is one plus: **reusable**.

Comment: I put it in a C function. There's no need for it to be an instance member of the array class, or even a static member. Adding it to NSMutableArray seems senseless, as it works just as well for other types of array.