# "for in" objective c empty array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, for-in-loop

I came to notice that executing a for/in operation in objective c on an initialized empty NSMutableArray was not working as expected.

Simplified code is :

```
+(void) convertArray: (NSMutableArray*)arrayIN {

    NSMutableArray *arrayOUT = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSLog(@"is nil %d - count %d", !arrayIN, [arrayIN count]);

    for(NSObject *o in arrayIN)
        [arrayOUT addObject:[o convertToAnotherClass]];

}
```

Actual code is :

```
+(BOOL) writeTasks: (NSArray*)tasksArray {

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"is nil %d - count %d", !arr, [arr count]);
    for(Task *t in tasksArray)
        [arr addObject:[t getDictionary]];

    NSError *error; 
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        return NO;
    } else {
        //NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [jsonData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

the suprising thing is that executing `[dummyClass convertArray:[NSMutableArray array]]` is showing this :

```
2012-06-25 13:51:34.236 Planorama[740:707] is nil 0 - count 0
2012-06-25 13:51:34.239 Planorama[740:707] -[__NSArrayM convertToAnotherClass]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde9b580
(lldb)
```

Why ? arrayIN is empty, why is `convertToAnotherClass` even called ?

Comment: Your code doesn't match what you're saying. You say that `arrayIN` is empty, but your `NSLog` refers to `arr` which is not mentioned at all in your example?

Comment: Oops, I tried to give explicits name bo forgot some of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use the block based enumeration it will work the way you want. 
Also, the output indicates that o is set to some instance of something, so you may have another problem.

[Elegant way to get all objects of a specific type in an Objective-C array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699135/elegant-way-to-get-all-objects-of-a-specific-type-in-an-objective-c-array)

Lastly,  it looks like this is a static method, but your example calls it as an instance method.

Comment: I may have miswritten it but this is called correctly and compiles without a problem. The only problem I have is that even an empty array declared using `[NSMutableArray array]` and showing a count of 0 is iterated..

Comment: I pasted the actual code. I thought it might be easier to simplify it, but it adds too much questions. So here it is !

Comment: yes, you are checking the length of the mutable array but iterating over the taskArray, which is passed in.  the newly instantiated mutable array is, of course, 0 length but the taskArray argument appears to have length > 0 in this debugging output.

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua Smith pointed out : I am not checking the count of the iterated array. The iterated array was not empty and contained itself because if a mistyped line :

`[tasks addObject:tasks]`

instead of

`[tasks addObject:task]`

in a previous method..

Thanks everyone !

PS : the link of Joshua Smith is very useful ! Future readers : check it out !